# Migrate Code Repository from Github to AWS CodeCommit using Lambda

Tags: docker, github, aws-lambda, aws-codecommit

I am trying to find a way to migrate Code Repository from Github to AWS CodeCommit programmatically using a Lambda.

I thought about one solution :

Using a lambda docker that runs on ubuntu, cloning the GitHub repository inside the docker and so push the code inside AWS CodeCommit using AWS cli.

Does someone have another idea or solution to achieve this?
Thanks for the help

Comment: Is there a reason to introduce Lambda and Docker? Are you unable to connect to Github and CodeCommit from the CLI on your local pc/workstation?